# Expose JavaScript partial to global namespace and call it?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails JS partial which makes some visualizations based on other data loaded into view. However, since JavaScript executes on a page load, I'm not sure how to to get it to execute when the partial is injected.

The partial is executed on the show action of my folder model. It looks like this:

```
$("body").append( "<%=j render :partial => 'contents', :locals => {:folder => @folder } %>" );
$("#jscripts").append("<%=j render :partial => 'show', formats: :js, :locals => {:folder => @folder} %>");
```

The second line appends my JS partial in with the rest of my JS between `<script>` tags in application.html.erb. My _show.js.erb partial looks like this:

```
d3Code = function(){

        d3.json("/folders/<%= @folder.id %>.json"), function(error, data) {

            if (error) return console.warn(error);

            var svg = d3.select("svg"),
            folderChildren = [],
            circle;

            var submissions = data.submissions;


            for(submission in submissions) {
                var submissionWords = submission.content.split(' ').join('');
                var size = submissionWords.length;
                folderChildren.push(size);
            };

            circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
             .data(folderChildren)
             .enter().append("circle")
                 .attr("cy", 90)
                 .attr("cx", String)
                 .attr("r", Math.sqrt);

            circle.exit().remove(); 

        };

};

d3Code();
```

As you can see I have wrapped it in a function called d3Code() then called it at the bottom. That doesn't seem to work. Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: Did you see this scripts being actually inserted into DOM?

Comment: Yes, it is being inserted. One thing I noticed is that the HTML is inserted after the JS. This might be the problem?

Comment: Actually, I tried inserting it before the JS but that didn't resolve it.

Comment: Check if code is executed at all, check if it is able to reach any DOM elements or external resources (json request) it may need. I have no idea how this code is supposed to work, what is `d3`, what is `d3.json` and why callback is passed AFTER `.json` method call.

Comment: Bottom line: this code makes no sense to me.